# How to foward NSView keyboard handlers to the main window?

Tags: cocoa, keyboard, nsview

I have a custom NSView implementing keyDown and keyUp methods, but it's actually a plugin and it is desirable to somehow send the keys to the host if the key strokes hasn't been used. Is there a way to safely forward the keyDown/keyUp to the main window of the application?

Comment: Do you want to ignore the events and send them up the responder chain or do you want to send the events directly to the window?

Comment: Directly to the main window, since ignoring it doesn't help, the responder chain seems to end here. It's a popup window.

Comment: Can you locate the window from plugin's NSView?

Comment: Is the main window `NSApp.mainWindow`?

Comment: Honestly no idea. It's a plugin, so it definitely did NOT create a main window. Let's say NSApp.mainWindow would indeed be the main window of the app, how to forward the events then?